# Package a Default for an FMA Date Feature Parameter

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, 2gp, feature-management, 1gp-package

**What is the goal?**

The goal is to track when the managed package was installed on the customer's org and be able to read the date on the customer's side.

**What is the current solution I am thinking of?**

1. Create a Feature Parameter Date flag,
2. Add it to the package,
3. Create an `after insert` trigger in PBO on `sfFma__FeatureParameterDate__c` object to populate the Date with the desired value.

**Is there any better/easier way to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reaching out to some other peers, it is indeed a good approach to set the default value that needs to have some kind of dependency (like the date should be set to `TODAY()` date).

**But** Feature Parameters allows us to set a default value that would be the same for all created Feature Parameters, so if you for example just need to set the Boolean value to `true` you can just set it that way and skip the trigger creation part.
[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_fma_create_feature_parameters.htm) is the reference for setting the value.